# Tooltip after each iteration in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am writing a script in QTP, which includes many iterations and test menus. I need to display a message in balloon tooltip after each iteration, that it is been executed. How to display tooltips in VBscript?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider showing what did you tried and didn't work or what you found in bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly tool tips but QTP exposes a `Print` function which writes to an output window. You can then follow the test's progress by the print messages.

Comment: I know about the Print Function, but I have been asked to display that iteration is executed after each iteration in the tooltip in system tray.

Comment: In  that case I would recommend writing a .NET or COM process that creates the tool tip and call this from `CreateObject` or `DotNetFactory`